# How can i restrict to paste the integer or character value in textbox (Aspx.page) through java script

Tags: javascript, asp.net

It is easy to put restriction on a textBox (Aspx.page) to enter only  integer or character value but how  can i restrict it while we paste .

Answer (score 0):

You can put JavaScript handlers into the `onkeydown` (which gives you the ability to cancel the keypress is necessary) but this is complex to put together... especially when it comes to copy/paste.

For integer values, it would be far, far easier to use  `<asp:CompareValidator Operate="DataTypeCheck" Type="Integer" ...`.  [See MSDN for more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.comparevalidator.aspx)

You've also got `<asp:RegularExpressionValidator...` which will allow you to check for specific strings. [See MSDN for more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx)

However, the validators are **not** designed to stop people entering the values into the textboxes directly, but designed to stop the form being submitted to the server if the content is incorrect, and also checked at the server before being used in the code (which you need to use `Page.IsValid`).

(As a side note, if you ARE restricting particular things via JavaScript, you really REALLY need to double check for restricted things on the server - as JavaScript can easily be bypassed)

Answer (score 0):

See the [FilteredTextBox](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/FilteredTextBox/FilteredTextBox.aspx) for an existing solution. Should be very easy to integrate on an aspx-page.

Edit: and also do note what freefaller said about server side validation.